# How to change word after match?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I would like to remove word after match:

I would like to change the following line:

```
Assertion failed: FILE: ../../test.cpp LINE: 350: error message:
```

to this:

```
Assertion failed: FILE: ../../test.cpp LINE: error message:
```

Comment: Is it just to remove the number after `LINE`?

Comment: what did you already try and that failed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$ echo "Assertion failed: FILE: ../../test.cpp LINE: 350: error message:" \
   | sed 's/LINE: [^ ]*/LINE:/'
Assertion failed: FILE: ../../test.cpp LINE: error message:
```